# How to reference a non-default folder of a shared Mailbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below folder structure in a shared mailbox (**test@outlook.com**)

- Inbox
- **TEST**

  - **T-SUB-1**
  - **T-SUB-2**
- Sent Items
- Deleted Items
- List item

How shall I reference **TEST** folder which is not outlook's default folder. And how shall I check mails on all the *subfolders* for **TEST**.

Here's the code, but this returns NULL

````
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ns          As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim olShareName As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim Inbox       As MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder   As MAPIFolder
    Dim msg         As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim msgcount    As Integer
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    
    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olShareName = ns.CreateRecipient("test@outlook.com")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox).Folder("TEST")
    Set Items = Inbox.Items 
    msgcount = 0 
    ....```
````

Comment: What do you get when you type `vba outlook shared mailbox subfolders site:stackoverflow.com` in Google?

Comment: I have tried 0m3r solution, but doesn't seems to work as this TEST folder isn;t the default Inbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the folder structure like a genealogy tree rather than the way it is displayed in the User Interface.

[image: Folder Structure]

From the inbox up to the parent of the inbox, down to the Test folder at the same level as the inbox.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    ' Reference to Outlook XX.X object library required
    Dim ns As outlook.namespace
    Dim olShareName As outlook.Recipient
    
    Dim Mailbox  As Folder
    Dim Inbox As Folder
    Dim firstLevelFolder As Folder
    Dim secondLevelFolder As Folder
    
    Dim i As Long
        
    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olShareName = ns.CreateRecipient("test@outlook.com")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olShareName, olFolderInbox)
    
    Set Mailbox = Inbox.Parent
    
    Set firstLevelFolder = Mailbox.folders("TEST")
    
    Debug.Print "firstLevelFolder.folders.count: " & firstLevelFolder.folders.count
    
    For i = firstLevelFolder.folders.count To 1 Step -1
        Set secondLevelFolder = firstLevelFolder.folders(i)
        Debug.Print secondLevelFolder.name
    Next
      
End Sub
```